# I have file containing relative paths to many files, how to print only names of PDF files from this into another file?

Tags: filenames

So I used the find command to write relative paths to files that meet certain criteria into a text file. Now, I want to process this file so only the file names are printed without the path. Thus, each line in the file must be parsed and if it contains name of a PDF file, the name must be printed to the screen. How to do this? This is basically a form of batch processing and I have not yet found a solution that can be used for file processing in this way.

Comment: use sed, grep or awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I setup a list of relative pathnames with some pdf and some not.

```
$ cat list.txt
../myfiles/some.pdf
../myfiles/another.pdf
../../old.pdf
../../notapdf.txt
../nowhere/pdf with a space.pdf
```

Then the script.

```
while read -r line; do echo $(basename "$line")

done <<< $(grep -i "\.pdf$" list.txt)
```

This will execute a case-insensitive grep on your list of files, to pick up .pdf .PDF or even .PdF files, assuming they are named as such. The basename command will strip the leading path and leave you with the filename portion and print it. This will also handle spaces within filenames.

The output would be:

```
some.pdf
another.pdf
old.pdf
pdf with a space.pdf
```

Hope that helps.